# SQL query to listAgg and group by

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I wrote a new query which gets me a listAgg result such as the below

```
               Col A
 1000016932,1000020056,1000020100,1000020144,1000020243
```

Now what i want with that results is as follows

`col C        col D
    1000016932   1000020056
    1000016932   1000020100
    1000016932   1000020144
    1000016932   1000020243
    1000020056   1000020100
    1000020056   1000020144  ...and so on`

Please note that I can't hard-code the levels as each string can be of any given length

Comment: In simple terms what i want is to get the cases in listagg then turn that listagg results into rows.  So if the listagg contains (abc; def) turn that into Col_1 = abc  column2 =def

Comment: The expected results appear illogical. The question is not clear.

Comment: change the question maybe it will make sense .

Comment: What you show in the question and in the comment mean different things. Are you trying to get one row for every possible combination of two different "numbers" from the input row? Using the logic from the question on the example in your comment, you don't want only Col1 = abc and Col2 = def, you ALSO want a second row with Col1=def and Col2=abc. Please clarify.

Comment: Sooo... You have a long string with comma separated values and want to parse the string and convert it into rows. but...  only half the string... then the other half in a second column.... arbitrarily?  Still not clear.

Comment: I have a string A,B,C,D and want results to show Row 1 = A  B , ROW 2 = A C, ROW 3 = A D, ROW 4 = B C, ROW 5 = C D.  Each row has two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with table_1 (colA) as (
        select '1000016932,1000020056,1000020100,1000020144,1000020243' from dual
     ),
     prep (lvl, token) as (
        select level, regexp_substr(colA, '[^,]+', 1, level) from table_1
        connect by level <= regexp_count(colA, ',') + 1
        and colA = prior colA
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select p1.token as token_1, p2.token as token_2 
from prep p1 join prep p2 on p1.lvl < p2.lvl;
```

This assumes there are no nulls between commas (you don't have two consecutive commas with nothing between them, marking a "null" in the sequence).

Result:

```
TOKEN_1    TOKEN_2
---------- ----------
1000016932 1000020056
1000016932 1000020100
1000016932 1000020144
1000016932 1000020243
1000020056 1000020100
1000020056 1000020144
1000020056 1000020243
1000020100 1000020144
1000020100 1000020243
1000020144 1000020243
```

To allow several rows in the input table (assuming there is a row_id column of some sort in the initial table):

```
with table_1 (row_id, colA) as (
        select 101, '1000016932,1000020056,1000020100,1000020144,1000020243' from dual union all
        select 102, '1000040042,1000045543,1000045664'                       from dual
     ),
     prep (lvl, row_id, token) as (
        select level, row_id, regexp_substr(colA, '[^,]+', 1, level) from table_1
        connect by level <= regexp_count(colA, ',') + 1
        and row_id = prior row_id
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select p1.row_id, p1.token as token_1, p2.token as token_2 
from prep p1 join prep p2 on p1.row_id = p2.row_id and p1.lvl < p2.lvl
order by row_id, token_1;
```

Result:

```
    ROW_ID TOKEN_1    TOKEN_2
---------- ---------- ----------
       101 1000016932 1000020144
       101 1000016932 1000020056
       101 1000016932 1000020100
       101 1000016932 1000020243
       101 1000020056 1000020243
       101 1000020056 1000020100
       101 1000020056 1000020144
       101 1000020100 1000020243
       101 1000020100 1000020144
       101 1000020144 1000020243
       102 1000040042 1000045543
       102 1000040042 1000045664
       102 1000045543 1000045664
```

Comment: I tried this and it works however what happens if i have two rows instead of just '1000016932,1000020056,1000020100,1000020144,1000020243'.  lets say i have now two rows.  Is it possible to make this query only do the operation per row.  That is lets say table_1 col_a contains two rows Row 1= 1,2 and ROW 2 = 3,4,5.  Can i make it return (1,2), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)?

Comment: It is possible, but before volunteers do any more work for you (I shouldn't speak for everyone - before **I** do any more work) please state ALL your requirements upfront, don't add them one at a time. This is taking time away from helping other posters. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Yes sir you are correct and sorry about that.  That is the last requirement there is nothing else left

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you need to get all combinations of pair of values inside a comma separated string where order is not significant, excluding the same value pairs like (1,1), (2,2), etc.

The first step is to convert the string into rows and select a rownumber along with the values -

```
    SELECT ROWNUM AS r,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_A,
                          '(.*?)(,|$)',
                          1,
                          LEVEL,
                          NULL,
                          1)
              val
      FROM my_table
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (COL_A, ',') + 1;
```

Then do a cross join with itself. However this would give you the same pair twice. So something like `{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)}`. In order to eliminate duplicates and retrieve the rows in a way you want - make sure that the second table's rownumber is greater than the first. This way you would get - {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)}.

So the final query looks like -

```
WITH my_table
     AS (SELECT '1000016932,1000020056,1000020100,1000020144,1000020243'
                   AS col_A
           FROM DUAL),
     vals
     AS (    SELECT ROWNUM AS r,
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_A,
                                   '(.*?)(,|$)',
                                   1,
                                   LEVEL,
                                   NULL,
                                   1)
                       val
               FROM my_table
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (COL_A, ',') + 1)
SELECT v_a.val AS col_B, v_B.val AS col_C
  FROM vals v_A
       CROSS JOIN vals v_B
 WHERE v_B.val > v_A.val;
```

**EDIT**:

Because there could be multiple rows, it a good idea to have some kind of an ID column using which you could tie rows together. So in this example -

```
ID  COL_A
1   1,2,3,4
2   5,6,7
```

The only thing that you need to do is to select unique rows based on the ID when splitting the comma separated string.

```
WITH my_table
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, '1,2,3,4' AS col_A FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, '5,6,7' FROM DUAL),
     vals
     AS (    SELECT DISTINCT id,
                             REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_A,
                                            '(.*?)(,|$)',
                                            1,
                                            LEVEL,
                                            NULL,
                                            1)
                                val
               FROM my_table
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (COL_A, ',') + 1)
  SELECT v_a.val AS col_B, v_B.val AS col_C
    FROM vals v_A
         JOIN vals v_B ON v_A.id = v_B.id
   WHERE v_B.val > v_A.val;
```

**EDIT 2**:

I realized I'm comparing the actual values and that's not correct. It would force all values to be an integer. Here is a query that would allow integers or strings.

```
WITH my_table
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, '1,2,3,4' AS col_A FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, '5,6,7' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'a,b,c' FROM DUAL),
     vals
     AS (    SELECT DISTINCT id,
                             REGEXP_SUBSTR (col_A,
                                            '(.*?)(,|$)',
                                            1,
                                            LEVEL,
                                            NULL,
                                            1)
                                val
               FROM my_table
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (COL_A, ',') + 1
           ORDER BY id, val),
     vals_r AS (SELECT ROWNUM AS r, vals.* FROM vals)
SELECT v_a.val AS col_B, v_B.val AS col_C
  FROM vals_r v_A
       JOIN vals_r v_B ON v_A.id = v_B.id
 WHERE v_B.r > v_A.r;
```

Comment: This also works but the same comment also applies to this answer too.

Comment: Just realized I'm comparing actual values instead of row numbers or levels. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote a new query which gets me a listAgg result such as the below
>   ...
>   Now what i want with that results is as follows

You want to take a step back as this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you had the data in rows and then aggregated it and then want to spilt it up again into rows then you could be doing it more efficiently by not aggregating in the first place.

Lets assume you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Now you could aggregate it:

```
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value ) AS "VALUES"
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id;
```

Which would give this:

```
        ID VALUES
---------- ------
         1 1,2
         2 3,4,5
```

And then start splitting the values up into rows again...

But it is much simpler to get all the combinations by just performing a self-join without aggregating in the first place:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.value AS value1,
       b.value AS value2
FROM   table_name a
       INNER JOIN table_name b
       ON ( a.id = b.id AND a.value < b.value )
```

Which will give you the output:

```
       ID     VALUE1     VALUE2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2 
         2          3          4 
         2          4          5 
         2          3          5
```